# Using Perl to get information between <div> tags on web page

Tags: perl, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to process a series of web pages which contain information I need inside a nested series of  tags.  Fortunately they have labeled the  tags I need with 'id' fields.  I've been over several stackoverflow questions that are similar to mine, but have been unable to get the samples provided in those to work for my problem.  I'm using HTML::TokeParser::Simple for my sample code since that's what all the other samples used on this site.  Here's sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(handle => \*DATA);
while (my $tag = $p->get_tag('div')) {
   my $id = $tag->get_attr('id');
   next unless defined($id) and $id eq 'rank';

   my $rank = $p->get_text;
   print "Rank is:$rank.hhhh.jjjj.kkkk.llll\n";
}

__DATA__
<body class="png_bg" style="background: #0A0A0A none !important;">
<div >
<div class="left">
<h2>Bob Smith</h2>
</div>
<div id="ranks" class="right">
    <div id="rank"><strong>Rank:</strong> 1&nbsp;of&nbsp;51</div>

    <div id="div-rank"><strong>Overall Rank:</strong> 1&nbsp;of&nbsp;1918</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

The output of the program is:

```
=> ./test.pl 
Rank is:.hhhh.jjjj.kkkk.llll
```

In a perfect world what I'm trying to do is get the text that follows the div id's of "rank" and "div-rank" in separate variables.

For whatever reason this is the only information stored inside of  tags on these web pages, everything else is stored in tables which I've been able to get much more easily.  However the ranking information contained in the  tags is important for my project.

What am I missing here?  Why is the value of $rank empty here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `as_is` instead of `get_text`?

Comment: Yes, below you'll see my response to another potential answer that I tried as_is, which did populate the variable but not with the value I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TokeParser is much too complicated. Declarative programming for the win!

```
my $html = <<'HTML';
    <div id="rank"><strong>Rank:</strong> 1&nbsp;of&nbsp;51</div>
    <div id="div-rank"><strong>Overall Rank:</strong> 1&nbsp;of&nbsp;1918</div>
HTML
```

---

```
use Web::Query qw();
my $w = Web::Query->new_from_html($html);
my $rank         = $w->find('#rank')->text;
my $overall_rank = $w->find('#div-rank')->text;
```

---

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath qw();
my $t = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$t->parse_content($html);
my $rank         = $t->findvalue('//*[@id="rank"]');
my $overall_rank = $t->findvalue('//*[@id="div-rank"]');
```

Comment: Thanks SO much!  I tried the Web::Query method and it worked great for my application!

Comment: FYI: in my case (Web::Query ver 0.34), in the above example, $html had to have '<html>' prepended to it in order the Web::Query part to work correctly.